# Android Management API change Policy for device

Tags: android, policy, android-management-api

I created 2 policies in my enterprise.

I would like to switch one device to the other policy without re-enroling it.

I tried to use android management enterprises devices.patch with following JSON

```
{ "policyName": "policy2" }
```

[this link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidmanagement/v1/androidmanagement.enterprises.devices.patch)

When i execute this command i always get follwoing error Message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Illegal state transition from ACTIVE to DEVICE_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

Does anybody know how to change policy for a device without wiping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i foudn a solution for my problem:

{ "policyName": "policy2" , "state":"active"}

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed possible to change the policy of a device without re-enrolling it, and you're not far from the solution.

You get this error because you implicitly attempt to change other fields of the [`Device`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices) resource (in particular the `state` field) by not setting them in the resource that you send in `devices.patch`.

You have two options:

1. Set the `updateMask` in `devices.patch` to `"policyName"`, to tell the API that you only want to change the `policyName` field.
2. Call `devices.get` to get the current `Device` resource, and then send back the entire resource with only the `policyName` field changed in to `devices.patch`.

Using `updateMask` is preferable because it does an atomic read-modify-write.

Answer (score 3):

As Fred mentioned, **updateMask** is the preferred way to go. Here's an example of how to use the **updateMask** approach in the Google colab

```
swap_result = androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().patch(
name='enterprises/ENTERPRISE_NAME/devices/DEVICE_ID', updateMask='policyName', body={ "policyName": "enterprises/ENTERPRISE_NAME/policies/NEW_POLICY_NAME"}).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try this from management api test site then add updateMask as "policyName"

[image]